# How do I avoid 401.1 during web service calls?

Tags: jquery, web-services, iis, deployment, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app which I am deploying to IIS 6 on a Server 2003 box.  The DB is SQL Server 2012 RC0 running on a Server 2008 R2 box.  I am using windows authentication, and the standard pages in my application work fine.  The user authenticates, the page retrieves & displays the data.  However, I have a couple pages in which I use jQuery to retrieve data from a webservice.  These calls are getting a 401.1 error.

HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

This, of course, doesn't happen on my dev box.  I've been Googling for quite a while, but haven't found a fix that works.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got this working, though I still don't know exactly what caused the error.  I was running my app under the default website in a virtual directory.  It was obviously a security issue so I tried a bunch of different security configurations between the default website & the virtual directory, but nothing cleared up the problem.  After I moved the app to it's own website, the web service calls got through.